# Write data in a view file in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I am trying to write some JSON data in a view file in CodeIgniter.

But it shows an error:

**`Message: fopen() [function.fopen]: Filename cannot be empty`**

The controller function is as follows:

```
public function write_in_a_view_file() {

    $data = array();
    $data['title'] = "Write This Title In a View File";

    $view_file = $this->load->view('result.php');

    $fp = fopen($view_file, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($data));
    fclose($fp);

}
```

Comment: Did you actually var_dump() $view_file to check what it contains?

Comment: The Codeigniter load->view function is a void function, meaning that it does not return anything (or returns NULL).  Thus you cannot fopen NULL.  Perhaps you could try loading the JSON data from your view?  Or load it as a string in your controller and then pass it to your view.  Either way would work.

Comment: Yeah seriously why would you want to rewrite a view file in a controller action. !?

Comment: Or if your goal is actually to write to a file, then you don't need to use a view at all.

Comment: @Ananth I need to write some json code in a fresh file

Comment: @MattBrowne I need to get the path of the file. But how?

Comment: Then directly send the new file path as the first parameter to fopen(), you don't need to load the view.

Comment: @JoelLubrano You are right. The view_file is NULL. But how can I get the actual path of the view file (result.php) in CodeIgniter.

Comment: Generally speaking, you shouldn't be writing data to a view file. View files are intended to be written by the programmer and act as templates that can render dynamic data (static views are also possible). So the *output* of views can change, but generally you would leave the view file itself alone. What is your actual goal?

Comment: There's a potential security concern here too...I would argue that files in the "views" directory shouldn't even be writable by the web server...you wouldn't want a hacker to be able to rewrite the views in your application.

Comment: @MattBrowne Thank you for your advice. My actual goal is to create a JSON file and store in a server; so I can use the JSON data in my   Android or iPhone App.

Comment: In that case I would recommend saving the JSON file somewhere other than in the `views` directory, to avoid confusion, e.g. `BASEPATH.'/public/result.json'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CodeIgniter File Helper for this.

```
public function write_in_a_view_file() {
    $data = array();
    $data['title'] = "Write This Title In a View File";

    $this->load->helper('file');
    $new_file_path = base_url() . '/path/to/file.php'; // modify this line to point to the actual location of the file
    write_file($new_file_path, json_encode($data));
}
```

Comment: public function write_in_a_view_file() {
    $data = array();
    $data['title'] = "Write This Title In a View File";
    
      $this->load->helper('file');
    $new_file_path = base_url() . 'public/result.php'; 
    write_file($new_file_path, json_encode($data));
    }

Answer (score 1):

fopen function takes 2 arguments, the first one must be the file name, while you are passing nothing to the first param.